# Uncaught Error: Call to a member function post() on null

Tags: php, slim

Hello I am getting this kind of error

> "Uncaught Error: Call to a member function post() on null"

Anyone mind to guide me how to make this code working?

Thanks in advance!

```
$app->post('signup', function() {
$app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
$name = $app->request()->post('name');
$surname = $app->request()->post('surname');
$address = $app->request()->post('address');
$contactno = $app->request()->post('contactno');
$username = $app->request()->post('username');
$password = $app->request()->post('password');
$app->response->setStatus(500);
$app->response()->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
try
{
$db = getDB();
$sth = $db->prepare("select count(*) as count from resident WHERE 
username=:username");
$sth->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->execute();
$row = $sth->fetch();
```

Comment: Which version of Slim Framework are you using? The syntax is of Slim 2. If you are using Slim 3, then see this url https://www.slimframework.com/docs/start/upgrade.html.

Comment: hellos ir can you help me what to change there? i'm a little bit confuse. Thanks!

Comment: Please add more details to the question, like the version of framework you're using, and how did you setup the `$app` instance. Right now there are several problems with your code.

Comment: that code is given by a friend because i'm not into php. If it is okay for you sir to help me. Thanky ou!

Comment: What line number is the error happening on? You've got a post method of $app, and you've got a post method of request(), but without more information about the line number, it's impossible to provide a good answer.